# How to update jlabel while running animation?

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, jlabel

I have a little animation where a rectangle, which is a jlabel with blue background, is constantly moving down the screen. I am running a thread to do this.

Now, i want to have another jlabel where it shows the current position of the rectangle.

```
public void run() 
{ 
    Pnl.requestFocus();


    x = (int) p.getX(); //find location of rectangle
    y = (int) p.getY();

    while (y < 450) 
    {
        RectangleLabel.setLocation(x, y); //reset location of the rectangle
        y += 10;


        try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } 
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            }
    }

}
```

Now i want to insert this code inside the while statement.

```
locationLabel.setText(String.valueOf(450-y));
```

But every time i do, the jlable updates but the rectangle doesnt move anymore.

How would i go about?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

Run This example

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.lang.*;

class TestThread extends JFrame implements  Runnable{

JLabel RectangleLabel,locationLabel;
int x,y=0;
TestThread()
{
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(null);
    RectangleLabel=new JLabel("Rectangle");
    RectangleLabel.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
    locationLabel=new JLabel();
    locationLabel.setBounds(200,200,100,100);
    add(RectangleLabel);
    add(locationLabel); 
    setSize(1000,1000);
    Thread t=new Thread(this);
    t.run();
  }
   public void run() 
 { 

while (y < 450) 
{
    RectangleLabel.setLocation(x, y); //reset location of the rectangle
    y += 10;
    locationLabel.setText(""+y);
    try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
    if(y==440)
    {
        y=0;
     }
   }
}
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    TestThread t=new TestThread();
  }   
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. this time it doesn't flicker anymore. it just stays there